# Get disctinct values from in a queryset django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have modelwith 2 foreignkeys.

```
class NewModel(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_g_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my queryset. It counts the number of male users but i want distinct number of male users from both the fields.

```
 male_count = newmodelqueryset.filter(
                Q(user_id__gender_id=male['id']) | Q(user_g_id__gender_id=male['id'])).count()
```

Comment: Please post your complete model

Comment: Imagine that there is a `NewModel` where both `user_id` and `user_g_id` are male, do you count this as one, or as two?

Comment: I count them as 2 but once the users are counted I dont want to count them again.

Comment: what is `newmodelqueryset` exactly? A `QuerySet` that already *filters* the `NewModel`s?

Comment: yes its a QuerySet that already filters the NewModel.

Comment: Try `.distinct().count()`

Comment: distinct() doesnot work .

Comment: What about saving obejcts in a `set` and getting it's `len` ? @Luffli

Answer (score 0):

Probably the filters will result in a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, such that the same object, but with different related object, is returned multiple times.

You can count the number of distinct primary keys with:

```
male_count = newmodelqueryset.filter(
    Q(user_id__gender_id=male['id']) | Q(user_g_id__gender_id=male['id'])
).values('pk').distinct().count()
```